# Viewing sets of images

Tags: ubuntu, images, navigation

I'm working on image processing software which outputs several large image files (10000 x 16000  or so). The output images represent different processing stages and are each overlayed on the same base input image.

To assess the quality of the output, I open up two images at a time. I navigate to the same coordinates in each image and alt-tab back and forth which gives a pretty good impression of what the processing did. The important bit here is that a single image is good for a quick glance, but I need to have two (maybe more) open to toggle through if I'm to do any serious analysis.

The problem I'm having is when I process a couple hundred input images at a time:
In_1 => Out_1_1, Out_1_2, ..., Out_1_n 
In_2 => Out_2_1, Out_2_2, ..., Out_2_n 
...
In_m => Out_m_1, Out_m_2, ..., Out_m_n

I'd like to be able to toggle though the Out_x_1 images until I see something interesting. Then quickly get to a situation where I can toggle through the input and all of the outputs associated with that image.

Working in Ubuntu...

Comment: I assume that knowing that the bytes are different at those points is not enough?

Comment: That's right. The bytes will differ in many places. The most important thing for me will be the ability to toggle between the input image and some output image (since the output is a processing stage overlayed on the input, parts of the input are obstructed by the overlay. Need to toggle back and forth to make sense of the overlay).

Comment: I've seen something like this... I'll try to remember what it was.

Comment: Oh, it was TinEye's thing for seeing how close the image it found was to what you put in. That won't help much, sorry.